# Cardbuilder to another cardbuilder

Tags: java, android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have implemented cardbuilder in a cardscrollview which show information for individual cardbuilder. Due to its limited view on glass, will only want to populate more information if the user taps on the cardbuilder.

Is it possible to have another cardbuilder to show more information of the cardbuilder when being tapped on? How could this be best implemented? I want to do this for every cardbuilder on the first level.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. When a card is tapped just start another activity containing a CardScrollView.